# Model Clashing With Namespaced Lib Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

In `lib/events/base/event.rb`:

```
module Events
  module Base
    class Event
```

and in `app/models/event.rb`:

```
class Event < Show
```

and in `app/controllers/portal/events_controller.rb`:

```
def new
  @event = Event.new
```

On `portal/events/new` I get this error:

> Unable to autoload constant Event, expected /my/path/lib/events/base/event.rb to define it

Since my lib class `Events` is namespaced, what is causing the clash? What's the simplest way to fix it?

Comment: I solved it by changing the order of my ```autoload_paths```, putting models before lib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by changing the order of my `autoload_paths`, putting `models` before `lib`.